# Why can't I change the value of a segment register? (MASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I decided to teach myself assembly language.

I have realized that my program will not compile if I attempt to change the value of any segment register.

Every article that I have found says that I can indeed change the value of at least 4 segment registers, so what gives?

I am really only interested in the why at this point, I don't have any real purpose in changing these addresses.

Comment: Under an OS, or freestanding? 16 real or 32-bit protected mode? What code did not compile? Minimal 16-bit example with observable effects: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/d4aae6183b98564819107b44a77641979c35d2c3/segment_registers.S

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视: I was after the concept here, not a code sample.  Also, this was seven years ago.

Comment: @EdS. date is not important, I learn every day from old questions and answer quite a few too :-) But I do understand if you forgot the details.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视: Well, that's true

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You said you were interested in why, so:

In real mode, a segment is a 64K "window" to physical memory and these windows are spaced 16 bytes apart. In protected mode, a segment is a window to either physical or virtual memory, whose size and location is determined by the OS, and it has many other properties, including what privilege level a process must have to access it.

From here on, everything I say refers to protected mode.

There is a table in memory called the global descriptor table (GDT), which is where the information about these window sizes and locations and other properties are kept. There may also be local descriptor tables on a per-process basis, and they work in a similar way, so I'll just focus on the GDT.

The value you load into a segment register is known as a *segment selector*. It is an index into the GDT or LDT, with a bit of extra security information. Naturally if a program tries to load a descriptor which is outside the bounds of the GDT, an exception occurs. Also if the process does not have enough privilege to access the segment, or something else is invalid, an exception occurs.

When an exception occurs, the kernel handles it. This sort of exception would probably be classed as a segmentation fault. So the OS kills your program.

There's one final caveat: in the x86 instruction set, you can't load immediate values into segment registers. You must use an intermediate register or a memory operand or POP into the segment register.

```
MOV DS, 160  ;INVALID - won't assemble

MOV AX, 160  ;VALID - assembles, but will probably result in an
MOV DS, AX   ;exception, and thus the death of your program
```

I think it should be pointed out that the architecture allows for heaps of segments. But AFAIK, when it comes to the mainstream x86 operating systems, segment registers serve only a few purposes:

- Security mechanisms, such as keeping user space processes from harming each other or the OS
- Dealing with multiple/multi-core processors
- Thread-local storage: as an optimization, some operating systems (including Linux and Windows) use segment registers for thread-local storage (TLS). Since threads share the same address space, it is hard for a thread to "know" where its TLS region is without using a system call or wasting a register... but since segment registers are practically useless, there's no harm in "wasting" them for the sake of fast TLS. Note that when setting this up, an OS might skip the segment registers and write directly to descriptor cache registers, which are "hidden" registers used to cache the GDT/LDT lookups triggered by references to the segment registers, in which case if you try to read from the segment registers you won't see it.

Apart from a segment per thread for TLS, really only a handful of segments (times the number of processors) are used, and only by the OS. Application programs can *completely* ignore the segment registers.

This is due to OS design, not to any technical limitations. There may be embedded operating systems that require user-space programs to work with the segment registers, though I don't know of any.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot load a segment register with an immediate value on x86? I am looking at Intel Architectures Software Developer Manual (325462, Combined Volumes) and on page 1002 it tells of a MOV instruction with an opcode of 0x8E, which apparently moves a `r/m16` into a segment register.

Comment: @amn: An immediate isn't a register or the contents of data memory.  Notice how the `mov r/m16, imm16` form of `mov` is distinct from `mov reg, r/m16`. 
 https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov

Comment: @Artelius: You wrote *Security mechanisms, such as keeping user space processes from harming each other or the OS* - but modern mainstream OSes don't use segmentation for that, they use *paging*.  (The CS segment is the mechanism for setting privilege level, so in that sense setting CS via `iret` or `sysret` is how the OS runs user-space code in ring 3 which stops it from taking over the machine.)  Also not sure what you mean by using segmentation to deal with SMP / multi-core systems.  Modern SMP kernels use a flat memory model just fine, except as you say for TLS with FS or GS.

Comment: I wouldn't say "a segment per thread".  The FS or GS base address will be pointing somewhere in a thread/process's virtual address space, but as you say it gets set that way via an MSR, not a GDT or LDT entry.  (Unless 32-bit kernels can't use `wrmsr`, and instead need to actually write a GDT entry and then reload the segment selector.)  But either way, it's not really a *separate* segment, and I wouldn't expect an OS to keep separate LDT entries for every task in the system, probably just write the same GDT entry.  Descriptor "caches" aren't really caches, they never silently refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing windows executables?

In protected-mode (Win32), segment registers are not used any more.

[Reference](http://www.codebreakers-journal.com/content/view/141/104/):

> Memory model is also drastically
>   different from the old days of the
>   16-bit world. Under Win32, we need not
>   be concerned with memory model or
>   segment anymore! There's only one
>   memory model: Flat memory model.
>   There's no more 64K segments. The
>   memory is a large continuous space of
>   4 GB. That also means you don't have
>   to play with segment registers. You
>   can use any segment register to
>   address any point in the memory space.
>   That's a GREAT help to programmers.
>   This is what makes Win32 assembly
>   programming as easy as C.

Comment: That's plain *wrong*. Several segment registers are used for thread local storage and exception handling.

Comment: I (obviously?) meant, "used for their original purpose, by user-space programs". OP was referring to out of date documentation.